# button click modifier in visual basic2012

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, button

I'm working on a coding problem for a class. One of the aspects is implementing a counter based on images (as each second elapses the image changes until it terminates at a specified time).

I've got almost completely figured out, except when a button is pressed, the countdown isn't reset. I'm trying to figure out a way to add an if then statement that says "if the guess or new game button is clicked then reset my counter to 0, otherwise continue"

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub btnGuess_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGuess.Click

Private Sub btnNewGame_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNewGame.Click

Private Sub tmrCountdown_Tick(myObject As Object, ByVal myEventArgs As EventArgs) Handles tmrCountdown.Tick
    Static Counter As Integer = 0
    Counter += 1

    Select Case Counter
        Case 0
            picTimer.Visible = False
        Case 1
            picTimer.Visible = True
            picTimer.Image = pic9.Image
        Case 2
            picTimer.Image = pic8.Image
        Case 3
            picTimer.Image = pic7.Image
```

Comment: Hint: You've chosen to use a Static for your counter. I can see why, but that may not be the best choice here.

Comment: it was sort of working, until I got to the button clicks. The posted answer solves the problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to move the counter outside of `tmrCountdown_Tick`, and ideally make it a non-static member. As in:

```
Private Counter as Integer = 0

Private Sub btnGuess_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGuess.Click
    Counter = 0
End Sub

Private Sub btnNewGame_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNewGame.Click
    Counter = 0
End Sub

Private Sub tmrCountdown_Tick(myObject As Object, ByVal myEventArgs As EventArgs) Handles tmrCountdown.Tick
    Counter += 1
    ...
End Sub
```

That way `Counter` is accessible in all of the Subs and Functions in your Form.

Comment: That's so simple and I know I would have never figured it out. Thanks so much!

Comment: @TrevorHopkinsBowers if this answers the question, the proper "thanks" on SO is to click the checkmark.  This helps others find good answers.  Soon (15 rep) you will also be able to upvote answer and questions you find which helped - another way to help other users find good answers.